# How do I animate a changing list in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items that is fetched from the server every 5 seconds:

```
$timeout(function fetchList() {

      $scope.images = Image.data();

      $timeout(fetchList, 5000);

    }, 5000);
```

and I display them in the document with:

```
<img ng-repeat='image in images' ng-src="{{image.filename}}" />
```

each time the timeout happens I would like to fade out the items that are no longer in the list and fade in the new ones. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for css3 animations. They are super easy.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is based on AngularJS 1.2.0, which differs from 1.1.5 regarding animation approach. I also used text list instead of images for simplicity.

First of all, the animations were extracted into separate module, so you'll have to load it:

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

and add **ngAnimate** as module dependecy:

```
angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"])
```

HTML markup:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <ul ng-controller="list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list track by item.id">Item {{item.id}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

CSS, the most important part:

```
li {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
li.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1; 
}
li.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;  
}
li.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
li.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

[Working example.](http://jsbin.com/aBAsinoL/1/edit)

**ng-repeat** provides three animation events to work with: *enter*, *leave* and *move*. Enter represents unique element being added into list, leave - being removed, and move, well, moving across it. In order to animate any of this, you just add two classes onto repeated element **.ng-*event*** (for animation start) and **.ng-*event*-active** (animation end) with desired CSS transition or animation.

Further read:

1. [ngAnimate documentation.](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/ngAnimate)
2. [Year of Moo article about AngularJS 1.2.0 animations](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)

Have fun!